# Is it true that recanalisation of the vas deferens, if any, tends to happen soon after a vasectomy (less than 1 year), and if so, why?

Tags: human-biology, sexual-reproduction

https://doi.org/10.1016/s0140-6736(00)02436-3 "*How reliable is a vasectomy? Long-term follow-up of vasectomised men*":

> Most episodes of recanalisation are believed to happen soon
> after vasectomy, and the pregnancy rate after vasectomy is
> about 1 in 2000. Delayed recanalisation after the first year is
> uncommon, only isolated cases are reported and its true
> frequency is unknown.

https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/326737#vasectomy-reversal:

> Most cases of recanalization happen within 12 weeks of the procedure.

Is it true that recanalisation of the vas deferens, if any, tends to happen soon after a vasectomy (less than 1 year), and if so, why?

Comment: This is a medical rather than a biological question as it relates to a surgical procedure. Try SE Medical Sciences.

Comment: @David Thanks, the recanalisation process is biological.

Comment: But your question does not ask about the biology of the process, but asks if it is true that it happens a specific time after a surgical procedure. It's up to you, but if I wanted an answer to a question like this I know where the most likely place to get an answer is.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that recanalisation of the vas deferens, if any, tends to happen soon after a vasectomy

Yes. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7175481/:

> - Studies have shown that early recanalization usually occurs between 2 and 6 weeks post-vasectomy [9, 10].
> - Early failure, defined as a postoperative semen analysis showing persistent motile sperm, occurs in 1 in every 250 patients [6].
> - Late failure, defined as the rejoining of the severed ends of the vas deferens, occurs in 1 in every 2000 patients.

Note that the same article reports of a case of paternity that occurred seven years after a negative post-vasectomy semen analysis, which means that  recanalization can happen many years after a vasectomy, even though the odds are very low (<0.05% after 1 year).

Also, the risk of recanalization may depend on how the vasectomy was performed. For example, see:

- [How does the length of the vas deferens excised during vasectomy impact the risk of recanalization after a vasectomy?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/24517/20241)
- [Does the risk of recanalization increase if a person chooses an open-ended vasectomy (which closes only testicular end of the vas deferens)?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/24506/20241)